# Sync 2 tables: one with engine = Memory another with engine = InnoDB

Tags: mysql, in-memory-database

I have 2 tables, student_memory (engine = Memory) and student_innodb (engine = InnoDB). student_memory is being updated continuously (at an interval of 2 seconds) by some thread. I have to sync both the tables (say at an interval of 10 seconds). I have some methods for that:

1. Create insert/update/delete statements by seeing the difference between the 2 tables and run those query on student_innodb.

2. Drop `student_innodb`, ALTER TABLE `student_memory` ENGINE = INNODB, RENAME TO `student_innodb`;

3. Truncate `student_innodb` table and do, insert into `student_innodb` select * from `student_memory`;

I'm using 2nd approach as this is saving me from comparing rows of the tables, creating `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` and executing them. But I'm not sure about the performance. There can be around 1000-100000 Rows in these tables. Can anyone suggest any other better solution or which one should I use?

Comment: May I ask why can't you just add two rows at same time, one row to `student_memory`, second to `student_innodb` every 2 seconds? Is it because they need to have same ids? If so you could write insert trigger on `student_memory` that inserts exactly the same row to `student_innodb`

Comment: Let's just say i have such requirement. after putting data in student_innodb, I'm reading it, doing some processing with the data, generating some value, and then transferring the generated values along with the read data to somewhere else. If i'll insert the rows in between student_innodb while processing the generated data won't be consistent, when I'll transfer them to somewhere else.

Comment: When processing data you could `SELECT max(primary_key_col) from student_innodb` and store it in some variable. Then in every next query add where condition ` primary_key_col <= max_val_from_variable`. It should work event when you add new rows to `student_innodb` in between your data processing.

Comment: what if some rows with id < max_val_from_variable gets updated??

Comment: I misunderstood that you only making inserts into memory table and need to sync new rows into innodb table. But you want to make snaphots od memory table every ten seconds right? If so then second and third method you have should be fine but you need some testing to check which one is faster with 100k rows.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, possibly the fastest way to do this is to have some sort of primary key on both tables (e.g. student_id).  You should then add a third memory table changed_students_memory that has only a student_id field as it's primary key.

Every time you make a change to students_table, you should:

```
INSERT (student_id) VALUES (:student_id) INTO changed_students_memory ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE
```

Then you have just a list of records to update in changed_students_memory.  You can then update your innodb table as such:

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE
  student_innodb AS i
  JOIN student_memory AS m USING (student_id)
  JOIN changed_students_memory USING (student_id)
SET
  i.<fieldname1> = m.<fieldname1>,
  i.<fieldname2> = m.<fieldname2>... ;

TRUNCATE TABLE changed_students_memory;

COMMIT;
```

This will be much faster if you're only updating a small percentage of the rows.  I'd also mention that under that assumption using the third table is preferable to adding a "dirty" column to the exiting memory table and adding an index on it, since most times the optimizer won't use the index since it won't think it's selective enough.

Having said all of that - I'm guessing that if you're doing all this craziness with an in-memory table, you're approaching your problem wrong.  In-memory tables are not meant to store data for long periods of time.  If the database goes down, you will lose your data.  If you have in-memory table as a performance optimization, you're better off tweaking your INNODB setup instead.  INNODB is very fast if configured correctly.  I have it easily handling load from hundreds of concurrent connections.  INNODB will keep all hot data in memory if you give it enough memory (see innodb_buffer_pool_size in my.cfg/my.ini).

Comment: thanks for answer, let's just say both tables are in innodb, (say innodb1 and innodb2). so innodb1 is being updated every 2 seconds, and every 10 sec I have to copy all the changes from innodb1 to innodb2 (may be some rows were deleted/inserted/updated from innodb1), so how to do this? i want to avoid comparing the tables and forming del/insert/update statements and then running them in transaction. that's why i was using a temp_in_memory table in which I was copying the innodb1 and then renaming it innodb2 (with alter temp_table engine = innodb rename 'innodb2'). can you suggest something?

Comment: Please read my answer above which shows you a way to do just that.  You keep track of which rows changed in a separate table, then use the UPDATE statement as I show above.  If you are also INSERTing into innodb1, then you can run the same INSERTs on innodb2 or expand on the idea from above to include flags for inserting records.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but for people that come from search engines (like myself) I should say:

NEVER implement any of solutions in above question, by first one you could get partially data lost and by two other solutions, you could get full data lost!

The best way is INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE data on innodb(or memory), and set AFTER INSERT/AFTER UPDATE/AFTER DELETE triggers to update memory the other table. So, you never lose data, but don't forget to enable Transaction for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE!

This way, you never get data loss, and it is very fast to read data from memory table. And Memory table will always get synced to Innodb one automatically.

1 Last thing: don't forget to config mysql to automatically sync this two tables at server start!